# How to extract an ID number from a list of consistently formatted strings

Tags: python, string

I'm working with a set of data that has names and usernames combined in one string. For example, if a user was named "John Smith" and his ID number was 1234567, the string would be "John Smith --- 1234567". The strings are consistently formatted in such a way that it is always:

```
NAME [space] 3 HYPHENS [space] ID number
```

I am trying to find a way to pull ID numbers out of these strings. I found that doing something like this:

```
foo = "John Smith --- 1234567"

bar = [str(s) for s in foo.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

I get a list like this ['1234567']. This will work for my needs, but I'm wondering if there's a more "Pythonic"/clean way to do this? Is there a way to just get and int of the ID number returned, as opposed to a list with a string in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this case

```
import re
foo = "John Smith --- 1234567"
id = re.search(r'\d+',foo).group()
```

Comment: This regex assumes no numbers in the names/usernames.

Answer (score 2):

Appropriate use of regular expressions is "Pythonic":

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "John Smith --- 1234567"
>>> idtext = re.match(r'.* --- (\d+)$', data).group(1)
>>> int(idtext)
1234567
```

The regex asks for any sequence, followed by your " --- " marker, followed by digits and then the end of the line. That may be too restrictive, or not restrictive enough, depending on the actual data.

Whether that's appropriate for your situation, and whether you want any error handling to cover possible unexpected conditions, is your call.  Note also [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which would let you do this on input that had many of these lines, all at once.

As Brian M. Sheldon commented, using a string split() (or rsplit(), if you're looking for something at the end instead) is also "Pythonic" when it's appropriate, and that would look something like this:

```
>>> data = "John Smith --- 1234567"
>>> idtext = data.rsplit(' --- ', 1)[1]
>>> int(idtext)
1234567
```

I showed the regex version first because in my experience, doing this on one line probably means you have a bunch of lines and going from the one-liner to using re.findall() makes this a bit simpler than having to iterate over the lines manually (using a for loop or generator or such) and apply the split to each one.

Comment: While I agree that an appropriate regex is pythonic, if the text is consistently formatted as mentioned, splitting on `" --- "` and taking the last value is both pythonic and quicker than a regex.

Comment: Also this regex could probably be improved, it takes a minimum of  18 steps for a 1 digit ID and 24 steps for a 7 digit ID as in the example.  By contrast `"--- (\d+)$"` takes only 9 steps regardless of ID length.

Comment: @Brian, the re.match() routine is anchored to the start of text. To get rid of the .* part you'd need to use re.search() instead.

Comment: Very true, but I find myself using `re.search` way more often than `re.match` unless the pattern really is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Brian, that's perfectly reasonable. For my part, I like to be quite explicit about what I'm actually skipping, even if it's just "anything". I figure it makes my code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly…:

```
id = int(foo.split(' --- ')[-1])
```

First, your `foo` is split into a list two parts - before and after `---` - then the last element of this list, which obviously should be the ID, is converted to int.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion, but you should probably explain what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
bar = [int(s) for s in foo.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

instead?

Comment: or `bar = [int(s[-1]) for s in foo.split()]`

Comment: @Michael instead split on the actual delimiter `foo.split(" --- ")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `str.isdigit`:

```
''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, foo)))
```

Comment: This is a heavy-handed approach in my opinion.  I think splitting on the delimiter is the better option.